# Can I stop robots from ruining statistics in Google Analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, visitor-statistic

I use Google Analytics to get visitors statistics on my webiste (PHP) and I see that a lot of traffic comes from sites like share-buttons.xyz, traffic2cash.xyz and top1-seo-service.com. I think this is because I use SEO-firendy URL:s (for looks in the addess bar).

This is not really a problem for the site itself, but when I look at the statistics in Google Analytics it includes these robots and non-users and the numbers are therefore not true.

Is there a way to block these robots or do I have to subtract the robots visits from the statistics manually every time I want a report?

Comment: _“I see that a lot of traffic comes from sites like share-buttons.xyz, traffic2cash.xyz and top1-seo-service.com. I think this is because I use SEO-firendy URL:s”_ – those have absolutely nothing to do with each other …

Answer (score 0):

If you see this happening you can prospectively exclude them from all future reports in GA by using a filter on that view (admin - filters, create filter, then apply to specific view)

[image: GA FILTER]

If you specifically want to do it proactively using PHP then you could use some regex to match undesirable referrers in request headers and return nothing.

Comment: View filters do not work retroactively, they work on incoming hits. You'd need an ad-hoc filter on the reports or a segment (and both have drawbacks).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the main question is yes, but it requires to be  be persistent and it is basically an ongoing task that you will need to perform. Yes, I know is a pain.

Just to let you know this has nothing todo with PHP or your friendly URL, your website is being a victim of what is known as ghost referrals. Google has not publicly said anything on the topic but just recently I found this article reporting that Google has finally found a solution [here](http://www.thesempost.com/google-analytics-referral-spam-removed/).

However, I choose to be sceptical about this. In the mean time this is what you need to do:

1. Make sure to leave a view untouched without any filters ([Read the fourth paragrah](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553?hl=en&ref_topic=6014102))
2. In Google Analytics > admin > view > View Settings> Check "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np07M7tC9Fo).
3. In the same view block spam bots: a) Check the list of ghost referrals in **YOUR REPORT** following [this method](https://www.ohow.co/all-the-answers-about-the-spam-in-google-analytics/#How-todetect-Spammy-traffic) and b) Create a filter [like this](http://www.cucumber.co.nz/blog/2015/january/14/ghost-referrals/).

I recommend you to read [this article](http://help.analyticsedge.com/spam-filter/definitive-guide-to-removing-google-analytics-spam/) in full that contains lots of details and more information.

Some people like to create filters with Regex listening all the spammy bots, if you want to check a up to date list visit [this repository](https://github.com/raulreyes/referrer-spam-blacklist/blob/master/spammers.txt).